# How to get a value from column 'A' in every 30th row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet from which I want to get values from column A of every 30th row.

I tried `=A(2+30)` but it just gives me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you would like your output columnar

```
 =INDIRECT("A"&ROW()*30)
```

somewhere in Row one and copied down as required should suit. (So you were close!)

Comment: Great, can you add an `ARRAYFORMULA` and perform a `SUM` as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula to capture every 30<sup>th</sup> row in the selected range:

### Formula

`=FILTER(A:A,MOD(ROW(A:A),30)=0)`

### Explained

- the `ROW` function returns the row number.
- the `MOD` function returns the remainder of the division by 30. Only zero is returned when multiple divisions can be made that in the end yield zero.
- the `FILTER` function filters out every instance that has yielded zero.

### Example

I've prepared an example file for you: **[every 30th row](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFNpNTI0cm83OTZPVVhQSEZRRDg4N2c&usp=sharing)**